# How to create arrows (with 3 lines) in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

[image: Up and down Arrow]

Above Image shows how i wish them to look like:

I have created some arrows which currently look like this:

[image]

here is the fiddle demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/yokeshsharma/a94a1grk/

```
    .arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  position: relative;
    width: 0.8em;
    height: 0.8em;
    border-right: 0.4em solid black;
    border-top: 0.4em solid black;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    left: 16px;
    top: 18px;
}
.up{
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.down{
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
.left{
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.right{
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

<div class="up arrow">
</div>
<div class="down arrow">
</div>
<div class="left arrow">
</div>
<div class="right arrow">
</div>
```

I have searched other questions most of them are specifically about creating triangles and arrows without the central line which i already created.
But I am not able to create the line in between, please help !

Comment: Why don't you use Font-Awesome or something similar?

Comment: i have used font-awesome before, but i wanted to learn this thing through css only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```css
.icon {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #323335;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

.arrow {
  height: 35px;
  position: relative;
  width: 10px;
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.arrow:before {
  content: " ";
  width: 10px;
  background: white;
  height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  transform: rotate(50deg);
  left: -10px;
}
.arrow:after {
  content: " ";
  width: 10px;
  background: white;
  height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  transform: rotate(-50deg);
  right: -10px;
}

.arrow-down {
  transform: rotate(-180deg) translateY(50%);
  bottom: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon">
  <div class="arrow"> </div>
</div>

<div class="icon">
  <div class="arrow arrow-down"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am glad i could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this one

```css
.container {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

.rect {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top:35px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #777;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.rect1 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    
}

.v-rule {
    width: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #777;
    top:-60px;
    margin-left:20px
}
```

```html
        <div class="container">
            <div class="rect"></div>
            <div class="rect1"></div>
            <div class="v-rule"></div>
        </div>
```